# Convert JSON string to Java Object using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse a JSON string to Java object.
The JSON string is as follows :

```
{
"token":"Hn2jqNYe75dOY5Xj2BmZTLAB",
"team_id":"T394M2RS5",
"api_app_id":"AC1UE8Y4C",
"event":{
  "type":"message",
  "user":"UC1C1D059",
  "text":"test",
  "client_msg_id":"bf824b77-c2ff-4cf3-b770-278168d006fb",
  "ts":"1533637676.000135",
  "channel":"DC2A6V4SZ",
  "event_ts":"1533637676.000135",
  "channel_type":"app_home"
},
"type":"event_callback",
"authed_teams":[
  "T394M2RS5"
],
"event_id":"EvC5BPR1N2",
"event_time":1533637676
}
```

I am using GSON to make the conversion, but i don't know how to 
design the Java class, because the JSON contains another object( the event object).
Any suggestion how to make the conversion? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried j[sontopojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) ?

Comment: First time i hear about it

Comment: it can help you to create Class from your json. Worth a try. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow documentation. It helps you to convert a JSON to a Java Class.

**Data conversions**:

- JSON Object - Java class
- Array - List<>

**Helpful links**:

- This is the library you need to **include** (tutorials included) in Java: [GSON Converter Git](https://github.com/google/gson)
- This is a **weather sample** of a JSON (example by coordinates): [JSON example website](https://openweathermap.org/current)
- This is an JSON to Class online **converter**: [Jsonschema2pojo generator](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

You can use jsonschema2pojo to convert the JSON to classes like **this**:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Clouds.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Clouds {

@SerializedName("all")
@Expose
private Integer all;

public Integer getAll() {
return all;
}

public void setAll(Integer all) {
this.all = all;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Coord.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Coord {

@SerializedName("lon")
@Expose
private Integer lon;
@SerializedName("lat")
@Expose
private Integer lat;

public Integer getLon() {
return lon;
}

public void setLon(Integer lon) {
this.lon = lon;
}

public Integer getLat() {
return lat;
}

public void setLat(Integer lat) {
this.lat = lat;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Data.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Data {

@SerializedName("coord")
@Expose
private Coord coord;
@SerializedName("sys")
@Expose
private Sys sys;
@SerializedName("weather")
@Expose
private List<Weather> weather = null;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private Main main;
@SerializedName("wind")
@Expose
private Wind wind;
@SerializedName("rain")
@Expose
private Rain rain;
@SerializedName("clouds")
@Expose
private Clouds clouds;
@SerializedName("dt")
@Expose
private Integer dt;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("cod")
@Expose
private Integer cod;

public Coord getCoord() {
return coord;
}

public void setCoord(Coord coord) {
this.coord = coord;
}

public Sys getSys() {
return sys;
}

public void setSys(Sys sys) {
this.sys = sys;
}

public List<Weather> getWeather() {
return weather;
}

public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
this.weather = weather;
}

public Main getMain() {
return main;
}

public void setMain(Main main) {
this.main = main;
}

public Wind getWind() {
return wind;
}

public void setWind(Wind wind) {
this.wind = wind;
}

public Rain getRain() {
return rain;
}

public void setRain(Rain rain) {
this.rain = rain;
}

public Clouds getClouds() {
return clouds;
}

public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
this.clouds = clouds;
}

public Integer getDt() {
return dt;
}

public void setDt(Integer dt) {
this.dt = dt;
}

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Integer getCod() {
return cod;
}

public void setCod(Integer cod) {
this.cod = cod;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Main.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Main {

@SerializedName("temp")
@Expose
private Double temp;
@SerializedName("humidity")
@Expose
private Integer humidity;
@SerializedName("pressure")
@Expose
private Integer pressure;
@SerializedName("temp_min")
@Expose
private Double tempMin;
@SerializedName("temp_max")
@Expose
private Double tempMax;

public Double getTemp() {
return temp;
}

public void setTemp(Double temp) {
this.temp = temp;
}

public Integer getHumidity() {
return humidity;
}

public void setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
this.humidity = humidity;
}

public Integer getPressure() {
return pressure;
}

public void setPressure(Integer pressure) {
this.pressure = pressure;
}

public Double getTempMin() {
return tempMin;
}

public void setTempMin(Double tempMin) {
this.tempMin = tempMin;
}

public Double getTempMax() {
return tempMax;
}

public void setTempMax(Double tempMax) {
this.tempMax = tempMax;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Rain.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Rain {

@SerializedName("3h")
@Expose
private Integer _3h;

public Integer get3h() {
return _3h;
}

public void set3h(Integer _3h) {
this._3h = _3h;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Sys.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Sys {

@SerializedName("country")
@Expose
private String country;
@SerializedName("sunrise")
@Expose
private Integer sunrise;
@SerializedName("sunset")
@Expose
private Integer sunset;

public String getCountry() {
return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
this.country = country;
}

public Integer getSunrise() {
return sunrise;
}

public void setSunrise(Integer sunrise) {
this.sunrise = sunrise;
}

public Integer getSunset() {
return sunset;
}

public void setSunset(Integer sunset) {
this.sunset = sunset;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Weather.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Weather {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private String main;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getMain() {
return main;
}

public void setMain(String main) {
this.main = main;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getIcon() {
return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
this.icon = icon;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Wind.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Wind {

@SerializedName("speed")
@Expose
private Double speed;
@SerializedName("deg")
@Expose
private Double deg;

public Double getSpeed() {
return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(Double speed) {
this.speed = speed;
}

public Double getDeg() {
return deg;
}

public void setDeg(Double deg) {
this.deg = deg;
}

}
```

After all is done you can do something like this in Java:

```
String config_settings = "Your JSON String";
Gson converter = new Gson();
ConfigSettings settings = converter.fromJson(config_settings , Data.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward:

1. Map each JSON key to a POJO attribute
2. Use `@SerializedName` to customize JSON key
3. Map nested JSON object to a class
4. Map `[]` to array
5. Map `{}` to object

And this is your result:
    public class YourClass {

```
    private String token;

    @SerializedName("team_id"
    private String teamId;

    @SerializedName("api_app_id")
    private String apiAppId;

    private Event event;

    private String type;

    @SerializedName("authed_teams")
    private List<String> authedTeams;
    .
    .
    .
}

private class Event {

  private String type;
  .
  .
  .

  @SerializedName("event_ts")
  private string eventTs;

  @SerializedName("channel_type")
  private String channelType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for GSON Library, you can create a package of classes that is identical to your JSON structure, for this, you can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and you can use the 
.fromJson() method, to transfer the JSON content to the container class.

Another thing is, you can transfer your JSON to Java Map class instead of creating your own classes.

But if you want it simpler, there are other libraries, for my preference, The easiest one to use is JSON Path: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath